# Mopub Interstitial not loading

Tags: ios, mopub

I am trying to test mopub interstitials with the test id in MoPub tutorials, the ios version is 10.2, MoPub outputs

```
2017-01-15 13:47:46.801224 Twit Miner[23775:6627095] MOPUB: Looking for custom event class named MPHTMLInterstitialCustomEvent.
2017-01-15 13:47:46.801321 Twit Miner[23775:6627095] MOPUB: Loading MoPub HTML interstitial
2017-01-15 13:47:46.999975 Twit Miner[23775:6627095] MOPUB: MoPub HTML interstitial did load
```

But I don't see any interstitial ad being displayed. You can find my code below:

```
import UIKit
import MoPub

class ViewController: UIViewController
, MPInterstitialAdControllerDelegate

{
    // TODO: Replace this test id with your personal ad unit id
    var interstitial: MPInterstitialAdController =
        MPInterstitialAdController(forAdUnitId: "77ce0b65cf81438eb255695afe3b1904")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.interstitial.delegate = self
        // Pre-fetch the ad up front
        self.interstitial.loadAd()
    }

    func interstitialDidLoadAd(interstitial: MPInterstitialAdController) {
        // This sample automatically shows the ad as soon as it's loaded, but
        // you can move this showFromViewController call to a time more
        // appropriate for your app.
        if (interstitial.ready) {
            interstitial.showFromViewController(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Even though log suggests otherwise, when I put a breakpoint, I realized that interstitialDidLoadAd method is never being called. I thought that it might be due to the ATS so I added the following keys to the info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

still no luck, can someone tell me what I am probably doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this may be too late.

Check if you have following log entry:

```
A location manager (0x143ebb150) was created on a dispatch queue 
executing on a thread other than the main thread.  It is the 
developer's responsibility to ensure that there is a run loop running 
on the thread on which the location manager object is allocated.  In 
particular, creating location managers in arbitrary dispatch queues 
(not attached to the main queue) is not supported and will result in 
callbacks not being received.
```

Just before:

```
MOPUB: Interstitial controller is loading ad with MoPub server URL:
```

If so, try dispatch `loadAd` method on the main queue like this.

**Objective-C**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.interstitial loadAd];
});
```

**Swift 3**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.interstitial.loadAd()
}
```